# python open file matching pattern excluding substring

Tags: python, regex, wildcard, glob

I need to open some files inside a folder in python

Say, I have the following files in the folder:

```
text_pbs.fna
text_pdom_fo_oo.fna
text_pdom_fo_oo_aa.fna
text_pdom_fo_oo.ali
text_pdom_ba_ar.fna
text_pdom_ba_ar_aa.fna
text_pdom_ba_ar.ali
text_pdom_ba_az.fna
text_pdom_ba_az_aa.fna
text_pdom_ba_az.ali
```

I want to open:

```
text_pdom_fo_oo.fna
text_pdom_ba_ar.fna
text_pdom_ba_az.fna
```

only.

I tried with glob:

```
glob.glob('*_pdom_*[^aa].fna')
```

But it doesn't work.
Many thanks to point out the problem in the above pattern. Is there any other work around for this?

Comment: What exactly isn't working w/ glob.glob?

Comment: It's not taking any file. The above pattern is not matching anything.

Comment: Ok, on testing, it would appear that glob doesn't handle the ^ part of range matches.

Comment: Perhaps, you can do it with `*_pdom_*[a-z][b-z].fna` or `*_pdom_*[b-z].fna`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `^` is not handled and must be replaced by `!`, You should try this code:

```
import glob
glob.glob('*_pdom_*[!aa].fna')
```

gives the result:

```
['text_pdom_fo_oo.fna','text_pdom_ba_ar.fna','text_pdom_ba_az.fna']
```

Comment: Might as well drop the second a in the brackets though since it doesn't do anything.